# Deleting usr/local/octave on Mac

Tags: macos, homebrew, octave

I have this folder on my Mac:

```
usr/loca/octave/3.8.0
```

It is taking up 2.3 gb. I don't really use octave anymore. Is there a safe way to delete this folder and save space? I ran `brew uninstall octave`, but that removed a different version of octave.

Comment: do you remember how you installed that in the first place? was it from source? (in which case there may be a place where you can run a `make uninstall` command?). Otherwise, if it looks like a "self-contained" installation, it's probably safe to just delete the octave directory

Comment: `/usr/local/octave` is a nonstandard installation location. It usually goes under just `/usr/local` or under `/opt/octave`. It's probably safe to just delete `/usr/local/octave`.

Comment: Okay! I deleted the octave folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to delete anything in `/usr/local` (as it is specific to user), and run `brew doctor` to verify if the cleanup is complete.

Even you accidentally delete something undesired, you can always reinstall to get it back.